# generate the empty field value

Tags: javascript

**first field**

```
  <input type="text" name="opt_name[]" value="d / ">

    <input type="text" name="opt_sku[]" class="a" size="3">
```

**second field**

```
<input type="text" name="opt_name[]" value="cv / ">

<input type="text" name="opt_sku[]" class="a" size="3">
```

[image]

**javascript**

```
<script>
$('#btnGenerateSku').live('click', function() {
    var empty = 0;
    $('.a').each(function(){
       if (this.value == "") {
           empty++;

          $(this).val('test');
       } 

    })

   alert(empty + ' SKU field generated ');
});
</script>
```

**Question : How can i generate the empty field value based on beside value when i click the generate button?**

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()` to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use `.delegate()` in preference to `.live()`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#btnGenerateSku').on('click', function() {
    var empty = 0;
    $('.a').each(function(){
       if (this.value == "") {
           empty++;

          $(this).val('test');
       } 

    })

   alert(empty + ' SKU field generated ');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="opt_name[]" value="d / ">

    <input type="text" name="opt_sku[]" class="a" size="3">


<input type="text" name="opt_name[]" value="cv / ">

<input type="text" name="opt_sku[]" class="a" size="3">

<br>
<button id="btnGenerateSku">Generate</button>
```

Comment: the second text box will be "text", i want to become first value. For example, first text box is  "d" when generate second box will become "d".Third box is "cv" when generate second box will become "cv".